# How prove $\frac{n(x^n+1)}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}}\le\frac{(n+1)(x^{n+1}+1)}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n}$

Tags: inequality

let $x>0$,and $n$ be postive integers, show that
$$\dfrac{n(x^n+1)}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}}\le\dfrac{(n+1)(x^{n+1}+1)}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n}$$

My try: it must prove
$$(n+1)(x^{n+1}+1)(1+x+x^2+……+x^{n-1})-n(x^n+1)(1+x+x^2+……+x^n)\ge 0$$
then I fell very hard prove it,maybe can use AM-GM inequality to prove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the inequality is invariant wrt. $x\mapsto \frac 1x$. So, it is enough to show the inequality for $x\geq 1$.

For $x=1$ it is true.

For $x>1$, to show is

$$\frac{n(x^n+1)}{x^n-1}\leq \frac{(n+1)(x^{n+1}+1)}{x^{n+1}-1}$$
or
$$f(x) = x^{2n+1}-(2n+1)x^{n+1}+(2n+1)x^n -1 \geq 0 \quad (x>1)$$
Since $f(1) =0$, it is enough to show $f'(x) \geq 0$ for $x>1$. Indeed, AM-GM gives
$$f'(x) =(2n+1)x^{n-1}(x^{n+1}-(n+1)x+n)$$ $$\stackrel{x^{n+1} +  n\cdot 1\geq(n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{x^{n+1}\cdot 1^n}}{\geq}0$$

Answer (score 2):

That last inequality looks equivalent to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(x^k+x^{2n-k})\ge2nx^n.$$
For each $k$,
$$x^k+x^{2n-k}\ge2x^n$$
is AM/GM.